# Issues with equal sign when assigning statement to @ variable for EXEC sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello: I am trying to encapsulate the following Insert and select statement into a variable for SQL to run.

The issue occurs when the equals sign is included for evaluation (or right around there)
The CustomPollerAssignmentID Column had to be cast since it natively a PK and a uniqueidentifier (see image)

What must be done to have the statement evaluate properly when passes to the sp_executesql?
I receive a syntax error as illustrated below

```
declare 
@date datetime,
@query nvarchar(Max)
set @date = getdate()-4
set @query = --'Insert into [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[BWC_VPN_Hourly_Long_Store]
                'SELECT * FROM [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Hourly]
                where Cast(CustomPollerAssignmentID as nvarchar(max)) = 63FEB60-4516-4C1A-9A11-DB30ACA44301'
                
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

[image]

**UPDATE-->**
I tried adding the single quotes.
While the statement does execute.. no results are returned. See Image below
[image]

Comment: GUIDs (`newid`s) need to be wrapped in quotes. You don't need to cast the column either. Your `WHERE` should be `WHERE CustomPollerAssignmentID = '63FEB60-4516-4C1A-9A11-DB30ACA44301'` (obviously escape the quotes for a "dynamic statement")

Comment: Why are you using `sys.sp_executesql` when there's nothing dynamic about your query? I also don't see the need for the variable `@date`, which is never used.

Comment: I attempted what you suggested with the single quotes and I received the error "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put it in quote like this `'63FEB60-4516-4C1A-9A11-DB30ACA44301'` , so your adhoc query would look like this :

```
  declare 
    @date datetime,
    @query nvarchar(Max)
    set @date = getdate()-4
    set @query = --'Insert into [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[BWC_VPN_Hourly_Long_Store]
                    'SELECT * FROM [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[CustomPollerStatistics_Hourly]
                    where Cast(CustomPollerAssignmentID as nvarchar(max)) = ''63FEB60-4516-4C1A-9A11-DB30ACA44301'''
                    
    EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Interestingly.. that did execute but no results were returned. I will attach an image to the original problem

Comment: @runatyr that's can be you don't have that cod in your table , investigate in your data , your code should be ok now

Comment: Thank you Eshirvana. In the second image i posted I showed the same  select statement in 2 separate windows.. the top window is a straight select and it returned data. the bottom half of the image was running it as suggested, with no data returned from the same table. Did I miss something? I'll triple check :) when i commend out the where statement data returns.. so something within the where section is failing to match and returning 0 results

Comment: codes are different , in your screenshot your code starts like 663F... but in your second select it starts like 63F... , so fix the code you are comparing

Comment: Annnnnndd You are correct... :) I truly appreciate your help in this matter. Please be well and enjoy your day know that you and this site have helped immensely.  Kindest regards !!